nodejs res.status().send() not returning correct status code
In my nodejs project a controller method not sending the status correctly back to the client.
user.controller.js
const User = require('../models/user');
const logger = require('../logger');
const UserOperations = require('../models/user.operations');

module.exports = {
    autenticateUser: async (req, res, next) => {
        const data = {};
        if (!req.body) {
            const err_msg = "Request body not present";
            logger.error(err_msg);
            res.status(422).send(err_msg);
            return;
        }
        if (req.body.username) {
            data.username = req.body.username.trim();
        } else {
            const err_msg = "Username not found in the request body";
            logger.error(err_msg);
            res.status(422).send(err_msg);
            return;
        }
        if (req.body.user_password) {
            data.user_password = req.body.user_password.trim();
        } else {
            const err_msg = "Password not found in the request body";
            logger.error(err_msg);
            res.status(422).send(err_msg);
            return;
        }

        try {
            const userData = await UserOperations.validateCredentials(data);
            res.status(200).json(userData);
        } catch (error) {
            const err_msg = "" + error;
            logger.error(err_msg);
            res.status(400).send(err_msg);
        }
    },
};

user.route.js
const express = require('express');

const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller');
const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post('/login', userController.autenticateUser);
userRouter.post('/create', userController.createUser);
userRouter.post('/edit', userController.editUser);
userRouter.delete('/delete', userController.deleteUser);
userRouter.get('/findbyusername', userController.findByUsername);
userRouter.get('/findbyemail', userController.findByEmail);
userRouter.get('/findbymobile', userController.findByMobile);
userRouter.get('/findall', userController.findAllUsers);
userRouter.get('/findbypk', userController.findByUserId);

module.exports = userRouter;

server.js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
    }
    return false;
}

// Referring models
const my_db = require('./models/database');
const User = require('./models/user');
const Customer = require('./models/client');
const Project = require('./models/project');
const Assignment = require('./models/assignment');
const Communication = require('./models/communication');

// Referring routes and controllers
const userRouter = require('./routes/user.route');
const clientRouter = require('./routes/client.route');
const projectRouter = require('./routes/project.route');
const assignmentRouter = require('./routes/assignment.route');
const communicationRouter = require('./routes/communication.route');
const errorController = require('./controllers/error.controller');

app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/client', clientRouter);
app.use('/project', projectRouter);
app.use('/assignment', assignmentRouter);
app.use('/communication', communicationRouter);
app.use(errorController.getErrorPage);

const port = normalizePort(process.env.APP_PORT || '5000');

my_db
    .sync({ force: false })
    .then(result => {
        app.listen(port, console.log("Server listening on port: " + port));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

When /user/login is executed from postman, I got proper error message in the log
30-Apr-2024 08:11:03.555 [error] -      No user found with username admin1
Reponse body in postman also came correctly.
{
    "error_msg": "No user found with username admin1"
}

But it came with Status: 200 OK, but in the code I sent status 400.

It seems like you are not throwing the error inside UserOperations.validateCredentials function, so it would be better to share the code inside the function

The problem is in line:
const userData = await UserOperations.validateCredentials(data);

The function validateCredidentials() should throw new Error("No user found with username admin1"), not return "No user found with username admin1".
This will take your program into the catch statement.
Optional solution:
You can also try to modify your code, but take note that we don't know how your validateCredentials() function looks like:
try {
  const userData = await UserOperations.validateCredentials(data);
  if(userData.err_msg) {
    res.status(400).send(err_msg);
  }
  else {
  res.status(200).json(userData);
  }
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error.message);
}

